# How to use Kafka consumer with asynchronous operation in Asp.Net Core App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, apache-kafka

I use Kafka consumer as a `BackgroundService` in Asp.NET Core 6 app. Initially, I didn't have a `Task.Run` in `ExecuteAsync`, but the `consumer.Consume` method blocked the application from starting. Wrapping the Kafka loop into a task solved the problem. But it was necessary to call some asynchronous method after the `consumer.Consume` method. How to do this so that there is no blocking?

I tried, for example, like this: `FooAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();` but this is not the recommended method.

I will be grateful for any ideas.

```
public class KafkaConsumer : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ICommand _command;

    public KafkaConsumer(ICommand command) => _command = command;

    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => StartConsumerLoop(stoppingToken), stoppingToken);
    }

    private void StartConsumerLoop(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        using var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(...).Build();
        try
        {
            consumer.Subscribe(_consumerOptions.Topics);
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                ConsumeResult<Ignore, string> result = consumer.Consume(stoppingToken);

                // How to call some async method:
                // await _command.FooAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
        finally { consumer.Close(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: In general, this is not recommended unless you want to have data be dropped and skipped. For example, offsets 0-5 could all start async tasks, but 5 finishes before the rest, and commits that offset. Meanwhile, any of the other records could fail processing, and you'd not be able to seek back to them easily to re-consume. You'd be better running an async task for a batch of records, for that reason, not one per record.

Answer (score 0):

using .GetAwaiter().GetResult() might can lead you to deadlock. so it is not recommended to use it. instead you can use async/await not block the thread and will wait for the operation to complete.

Here is the modified code you can give it try:

```
public class KafkaConsumer : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ICommand _command;

    public KafkaConsumer(ICommand command) => _command = command;

    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        return StartConsumerLoop(stoppingToken);
    }

    private async Task StartConsumerLoop(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        using var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(...).Build();
        try
        {
            consumer.Subscribe(_consumerOptions.Topics);
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                ConsumeResult<Ignore, string> result = consumer.Consume(stoppingToken);

                await _command.FooAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        { 
            // Handle the exception appropriately
        }
        finally 
        {
            consumer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This link mention the similar issue: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/487